# Crash in creating an array in the heap and delete it with/without shared_ptr

Tags: c++, new-operator, shared-ptr, delete-operator

I am fully aware that if I want to create a smart pointer to an array the best way is to use

```
     boost::shared_array<T>( new T[20] );
```

What I don't understand is the crash I have when a shared pointer of this type gets out of scope.

```
     boost::shared_ptr<T>( new T[20] );
```

I always thought that the code above would create a leak since it calls delete on the first element of the array by leaving untouched the others but this is not the case and I have a segmentation fault.

Can you help me understanding why? I have worst behavior if I don't use the shared pointer but a plain vanilla pointer

```
       CMyClass *p = new CMyCLass[10];
       ///....do stuff
       delete p;

       *** glibc detected *** ./test: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x088eb00c ***
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Can you help me understanding why? I have worst behavior if I don't use the shared pointer but a plain vanilla pointer**

Because your code has an **Undefined Behavior**.

```
CMyClass *p = new CMyCLass[10];
///....do stuff
delete []p;
      ^^^^ <-------------that is Missing!
```

You need to use `delete []`.

1. If you allocated using `new` you must use `delete`.
2. If you allocated using `new []` you must use `delete []`

Doing otherwise leads to **Undefined Behavior**. And one its Undefined Behavior then your program might show any behavior.It might crash or work or whatever(literally) so all safe bets are off.

> **How to use custom deallocation with `shared_ptr`?**

For `shared_ptr` you should use your own custom deletor function to deallocate appropriately. In case of array allocation using `new []`, you need to use `delete []`. Something like:

```
template
class CustomDeleter
{
public:
    void operator () (T* d) const
    {
        delete [] d;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    std::shared_ptr array(new Myclass[256], CustomDeleter());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh! THat's why! The response I was looking for was the "Undefined Behavior". THe reason is that when I used to do that kind of mistake I remember that nothing happened and the program was silently continuing its execution. One piece more of C++ awarnes so, ALS, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If an element it `new`ed, it needs to be `delete`d.  If it is `new[]`ed, it needs to be `delete[]`d.

I suspect that your problem arises when the shared_ptr tries to `delete` instead of `delete[]` the element.

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate an array using `new T[N]()` you have to call `delete []` to free it, but your `shared_ptr` calls `delete` which causes the error. The easiest way is to use `boost::shared_array<T>` to store arrays in a ref counted pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an array of smart pointers?